# Why CompletionItemProvider not work when enter charactor?

Tags: monaco-editor, visual-studio-monaco

I have uploaded my code at https://github.com/Hfutsora/monaco-kaco.

Steps to reproduce:

1. Open github page https://hfutsora.github.io/monaco-kaco/
2. Enter char 'O' at the endline then you can get suggestion
   [image: provide suggestions]
3. Enter char 'O' before the endline there are no suggestions appeared
   [image: none suggestion]

Comment: Have you checked that your provider returns the same suggestions in both situations?

Comment: I provide the same suggestions here. https://github.com/Hfutsora/monaco-kaco/blob/main/src/providers/CompletionProvider.ts

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem is that VS Code filters out your candidates because it gets the wrong `already typed` characters. In my completion providers I use a different method:

```js
const info = model.getWordUntilPosition(position);
```

which finds the word **before** the current caret position.

Comment: I have checked the suggestions' range and found `monaco.languages.CompletionItem.range` note that The range must be a single line and it must contain the position at which completion has been requested.  

So the problem was provided the error range because when enter before the endline, position.lineNumber and model.getLineCount() were not the sameline!

Answer (score 0):

[CompletionItem.Range Note](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NSTWW.png)

The range in CompletionItem must be a SingleLine, I provided a error range with different startLine and endLine, I thought this was the problem.

```
monaco.Range({
  position.lineNumber,
  word?.startColumn ?? position.column,
  model.getLineCount(), // not the same line
  model.getLineMaxColumn(model.getLineCount())
})
```